# UnsatisfiedLinkError in companion object Kotlin JNI

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm converting code from Java to Kotlin in one of my mobile apps, and the code that worked in Java stopped working in Kotlin. It uses JNI bridge to call C++ code.

Kotlin method declaration:

```
class Converter{  
    companion object {
        external fun convertNative(width: Int, height: Int, row: Int, input: ByteArray, ft: Int, output: ByteArray)
    }
}
```

.cc code:

```
   extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL OBJECT_TRACKER_METHOD(convertNative)(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jint row,
    jbyteArray input, jint ft, jbyteArray output);
}
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL OBJECT_TRACKER_METHOD(convertNative)(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jint row,
    jbyteArray input, jint ft, jbyteArray output) {...}
```

the error I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:No implementation found for void com.sampleapp.Converter$Companion.convertNative(int,int,int,byte[],int,byte[])(tried Java_com_sampleapp_Converter_00024Companion_convertNative and Java_com_sampleapp_Converter_00024Companion_convertNative__III_3BI_3B) at com.sampleapp.Converter$Companion.convertNative(Native Method)...
```

The original JAVA method (this works fine)

```
protected static native void convertNative(
      int width, int height, int row, byte[] input, int ft, byte[] output);
```

Also the library is properly loaded using System.loadLibrary (I see correct log output, no errors) in both cases.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to avoid changing the C++ code you should annotate the Kotlin function with `@JvmStatic`, i.e:

```
@JvmStatic external fun convertNative(width: Int, height: Int, row: Int, input: ByteArray, ft: Int, output: ByteArray)
```

By the way, your C++ function declaration is technically incorrect: For static methods, the second parameter is a `jclass`, not a `jobject`.

Comment: Yes, that was the case of missing @JvmStatic, thanks a lot!